# Java: Executor, FutureTask, Unsafe.unpark - how to prevent printStackTrace?

Tags: java, multithreading, futuretask, printstacktrace

In Java I am using FutureTask to run a Callable asynchronously via Executor. In order to check if an error occurred from the calling thread, I need to throw potential exceptions from the Callable. This however, leads to the stacktrace printed out to System.out (I debugged and this happens inside Unsafe.unpark(Thread) from LockSupport.unpark(Thread)).

Any ideas how I could prevent this?

I already log the exception to a real logger before (via SLF4J) and never want direct stacktraces on System.out.

Update: I think I already pointed out the relevant information but to clarify all the questions:
This test case can reproduce the Problem (Method testTransferStreamAsyncCallbackFail()):
https://github.com/m-m-m/util/blob/master/io/src/test/java/net/sf/mmm/util/io/base/StreamUtilTest.java

The implementation used is this:

```
public AsyncTransferrer transferAsync(InputStream inStream, OutputStream outStream, boolean keepOutStreamOpen, TransferCallback callback) {
    StreamTransferrer transferrer = new StreamTransferrer(inStream, outStream, keepOutStreamOpen, callback);
    AsyncTransferrerImpl task = new AsyncTransferrerImpl(transferrer);
    this.executor.execute(task);
    return task;
  }
```

I debugged through the eniter code and it is definetly not my code that logs to the console. This is done in the JDK as I tried to explain.

Additional Update to answer the questions:

The executor I am using is Executors.defaultThreadFactory()
As you can see here:
https://github.com/m-m-m/util/blob/master/core/src/main/java/net/sf/mmm/util/concurrent/base/SimpleExecutor.java#L30
https://github.com/m-m-m/util/blob/master/io/src/main/java/net/sf/mmm/util/io/base/StreamUtilImpl.java#L165

The output is the stacktrace of the Exception that I throw in my test from the Callable:

```
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: net.sf.mmm.util.io.api.RuntimeIoException: IO: An unexpetected error has occurred while copying data!
23355443-dae9-4f4e-87a2-fe38b8a3d513
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:192)
    at net.sf.mmm.util.io.base.StreamUtilImpl$AsyncTransferrerImpl.get(StreamUtilImpl.java:1)
    at net.sf.mmm.util.io.base.StreamUtilTest.testTransferStreamAsyncCallbackFail(StreamUtilTest.java:171)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:86)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:678)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
Caused by: net.sf.mmm.util.io.api.RuntimeIoException: IO: An unexpetected error has occurred while copying data!
23355443-dae9-4f4e-87a2-fe38b8a3d513
    at net.sf.mmm.util.io.base.StreamUtilImpl$BaseTransferrer.transfer(StreamUtilImpl.java:533)
    at net.sf.mmm.util.io.base.StreamUtilImpl$BaseTransferrer.call(StreamUtilImpl.java:583)
    at net.sf.mmm.util.io.base.StreamUtilImpl$BaseTransferrer.call(StreamUtilImpl.java:1)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: This is a test!
    at net.sf.mmm.util.io.base.StreamUtilTest.testTransferStreamAsyncCallbackFail(StreamUtilTest.java:155)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:86)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:678)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
```

Comment: Just curious, why does your Callable _need_ to throw an exception?  The javadoc for the ExecutorService interface does not say what an implementation is supposed to do when a Callable throws.  ThreadPoolExecutor appears to catch the exception and offer it to its own afterExecute(...) method.  That method is supposed to do nothing by default.

Comment: I'm not sure what System.out you're referring to (maybe the Sys.err that prints when printing stack trace?). Please give us more info on the situation (what printed out?)

Comment: Are you instead trying to direct the stacktraces to the SLF4J logger?

Comment: What executor do you use?

Comment: Btw are you really sure it is printed inside the executor? SLF4J by default prints exceptions to System.err.

Comment: > Just curious, why does your Callable need to throw an exception?
...
Nobody has to do that. But I tried to explain that I need to do it in my JUnit to test a specific behaviour of the error handling.